# Group schemes for beginners

Tags: group-schemes

Which book/notes would you advise for someone who knows (a little) scheme theory but not group scheme theory ?

I am looking for some notes where everything is explained, and where there are lots of examples and corrected exercices.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a good book : Goren, Lectures on Hilbert modular varieties and modular forms. There is an annexe (the first one) about group schemes with lots of examples and exercices.